# Use Plot.ly with external script for graphs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, plotly

I'm using Plot.ly.js to add some graphs to my website. I am trying to use an external script to draw the graphs because I'll be using the same function on several different pages. At the beginning of my .aspx page, I have this:

```
<script src="Scripts/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

so that I can use the Plot.ly library. In an external .js file, I have my function:

```
function drawLines() {
var one = {
   x: [1,2,3],
   y: [1,2,3],
   mode: 'lines+markers',
   name: 'Sample Data'
};
var data = [one];
var layout = { title: 'Sample Graph' };
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

If I put that directly in my .aspx page, then it works fine, but I really want to have it be external. So, I tried adding this where I want the graph to go:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
    <script src="Scripts/LineCharts.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>  
    <script>
           drawLines()
       </script>
</div>
```

I also tried putting the line with src="Scripts....> in the beginning, where I do that for the Plot.ly library, as well. Anyway, neither of them worked; the graph just doesn't show up on the page (but the div element with the blank space is there). I know I should be able to use an external script quite easily, but I just don't know where/how to put it into my .aspx page so that it works. I want it to run when the page initially loads.

I realize this is very basic and probably a stupid question but I haven't worked with these things before and I could really use some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save your script as an external file, you no longer have access to the HTML div "myDiv". You need to explicitly get a reference to the div by adding the following to the beginning of your script:

`var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');`

And now in your call to the `Plotly.newPlot` you need to pass that variable itself, not the string id, i.e.

`Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, data, layout);`

Also, this is more of a coding style issue, but you should call `drawLines()` in your external script, not in an inline script within the HTML.

Hope this helps!